# infinity series of $\sum_{n=M}^{\infty}\frac{na^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi I'm self studying calculus, I tried wolframalpha and it says [it converges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20n(a%5En%2F(n!)),%20n%3DM%20to%20infinity) but the final form looks odd, I'm hoping that it converges to a simpler form like what $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{na^n}{n!} = ae^a$$ converges to according to wikipedia. What does $\sum_{n=M}^{\infty}\frac{na^n}{n!}$ converges to if it's offset?

Comment: It does converge, to what you say it does. I'm confused by your question, what offset are you asking about?

Comment: @platty n begins at M

Answer (score 2):

It is tied to a special, however analytical function:  the [Lower Partial Regularized Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables) function $ {\gamma (x,a) / \Gamma (x)} $
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \over {e^{\,a} }} = {{\Gamma (x,a)} \over {\Gamma (x)}} = Q(x,a)  \cr 
  & {{\sum\limits_{k = x}^\infty  {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \over {e^{\,a} }}
 = {{e^{\,a}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \over {e^{\,a} }} = {{\gamma (x,a)} \over {\Gamma (x)}} = 1 - Q(x,a) \cr} 
$$
and $Q(x,a)$ is the [Upper Incomplete Regularized Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables) function.

In fact your sum is

$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = x}^\infty  {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{x - 1} {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = a\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{{a^{\,k - 1} } \over {\left( {k - 1} \right)!}}} 
 - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k - 1} } \over {\left( {k - 1} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = a\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 2} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \right)
 = ae^{\,a} \left( {1 - Q(x - 1,a)} \right) \cr} 
$$

where $x$ is your $M$, but can be also a real or complex number.

*--  Addendum --*

Let me add some notes to clear how the *Truncated Taylor expansion* of $e^x$ is connected with the
[Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and its corresponding "truncated" versions called [Incomplete (lower and upper) Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
Clearly, the notes here will be just concise hints, to stimulate and address your curiosity to the many treatises available on the subject.

The Gamma function is a $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ defined by the functional relation and /or  integral transform
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Gamma (z + 1) = z\,\Gamma (z)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \Gamma (n + 1) = n!\quad \left| {\;n \in N} \right.  \cr 
  & \Gamma (z) = \int_{t\, = \,0}^{\,\infty } {t^{\,z - 1} e^{\, - t} dt}  \cr} 
$$
(details about domain, convergence, etc. omitted)

The  [the Lower ($\gamma(z,x)$) and the Upper ($\Gamma(z,x)$) Incomplete Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) functions, and
the [Regularized version of the Upper Incomplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables) function ($Q(z,x)$), are defined as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \gamma (z,x) = \int_{t\, = \,0}^{\,x} {t^{\,z - 1} e^{\, - t} dt} \quad \Gamma (z,x) = \int_{t\, = \,x}^{\,\infty } {t^{\,z - 1} e^{\, - t} dt}   \cr 
  & \gamma (z,x) + \Gamma (z,x) = \Gamma (z)\quad Q(z,x) = {{\Gamma (z,x)} \over {\Gamma (z)}} = 1 - {{\gamma (z,x)} \over {\Gamma (z)}} \cr} 
$$

Then (very concisely) we have the following chain of relations
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Gamma (1,x) = \int_{t\, = \,x}^{\,\infty } {e^{\, - t} dt}  = e^{\, - x} \quad Q(0,x) = 0  \cr 
  & \Gamma (z + 1,x) = \int_{t\, = \,x}^{\,\infty } {t^{\,z} e^{\, - t} dt}
  =  - \left. {t^{\,z} e^{\, - t} } \right|_{t\, = \,x}^{\,\infty }  + z\int_{t\, = \,x}^{\,\infty } {t^{\,z - 1} e^{\, - t} dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = x^{\,z} e^{\, - x}  + z\Gamma (z,x) = z\Gamma (z,x) + x^{\,z} \Gamma (1,x)  \cr 
  & \Delta _{\,z} Q(z,x) = Q(z + 1,x) - Q(z,x) = {{x^{\,z} e^{\, - x} } \over {\Gamma \left( {z + 1} \right)}}  \cr 
  & Q(z,x) = e^{\, - x} \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\,z} {{{x^{\,k} } \over {\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)}}} \quad \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;z \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr 
  \;x \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & Q(n,x) = e^{\, - x} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{{x^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;n \in \mathbb N \hfill \cr 
  \;x \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
where
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\,z} {f(k)} 
$$
indicates the [Indefinite Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum).

Also refer to [this Introduction](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/introductions/Gammas/05/) given at Wolfram Functions Site.

So $Q(n,x)$ is the ratio of the truncated wrt the complete exponential series 
$$
Q(n,x) = {{\Gamma (n,x)} \over {\Gamma (n)}} = {{\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{{x^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \over {e^{\,x} }}
$$
(which of course does not imply that $\Gamma(n)=e^x$)

For small integral values of $n$ you just have a simple polynomial $/e^x$.
But if $n$ has large values, or if you want to perform some analysis on that ( in case extending it to non integral values),
then you can take advantage of the expression through the Gamma related functions.

Comment: I didn't really understand what $\Gamma$ was when I saw it in wolframalpha's answer, your answer helps. But why is $\Gamma(x)=e^a$ while $\Gamma(x,a) = $ the sum? what happens to $\Gamma$ when it only takes one parameter x?

Comment: well, I am going to add some more details about in my answer. However, if you are not familiar with the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and you actually want to understand what your sum represents (with $M$ integer , but also real or complex), I do suggest that you jump out of W. Alpha and pass and study some papers about .. Gamma (which is a **capital** function, being the extension of $n!$ to non integer arguments)

Answer (score 1):

It converges to

$$ae^a-\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{na^n}{n!}$$

for example

$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n!}=e-2$$

Comment: I thought about breaking it down but how do you find the closed form of $\sum^{M-1}_{n=0}\frac{na^n}{n!}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=M}^{\infty}\frac{na^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{na^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{na^n}{n!} = ae^a  -\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{na^n}{n!}.$$

I can't post a comment, but when you're asking for a closed form for $$\sum_{n=0}^{M-1}\frac{na^n}{n!}$$

I'm not sure what you mean, since it already is a closed form ($M \in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: something like this: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Comment: @user14042 I see. It doesn't reduce to something like that. You can use some other named functions or properties but that doesn't achieve anything and complicates it in my opinion.

Comment: How do we know it's not reducible?